# Does IntersectionObserver support horizontal scrolling observation?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I made a couple of vertical scroll IntersectionObserver modules, but I'm interested in horizontal scroll (root will be a div and observation target will be an img). I want to observe the changes when the img becomes enlarged but the div remains the width of the viewport. I'm not even sure that mobile Safari will report a zoomed img as having a changed width, this is an experiment. Back to the question though, I haven't found any info. re: observing horizontal intersection so I'm not sure if that's supported?

Comment: Intersection observers aren't inherently related to scrolling at all. They just observe how much of the element is inside the view port; whether that changed because of a horizontal or vertical scroll, a CSS change, or something else doesn't matter.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk ok so in your experience horizontal scroll is supported?

Answer (score 7):

To get an `IntersectionObserver` only in the x axis you can add to the options: `rootMargin: "4000px 0px 4000px 0px"`.

Comment: We should mention here that root Margin works when specifying the root element.

Comment: `rootMargin` supports %, so this could also be `rootMargin: "100% 0 100% 0"`.

Comment: @JustinAnderson it should be `rootMargin: "100% 0% 100% 0%"` or else an error is given
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'Intersection': rootMargin must be specified in pixels or percent.