# How to trigger intersection observer on horizontal scroll?

Tags: javascript, webapi, intersection-observer

Is there anyway to trigger Horizontal Intersection using the intersection Observer?

Comment: Consider reading about it and providing a [mcve]? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310068/does-intersectionobserver-support-horizontal-scrolling-observation help?

Comment: Tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310068/does-intersectionobserver-support-horizontal-scrolling-observation already. didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.